# How to keep children while rerendering parent?

Tags: reactjs

Whenever `catName` or `catWeight` are updated, it re-renders `categories`, but it has children that I want to keep. I tried using `React.memo()` to no avail. What do I do? Is it better to keep children and rerender the parent or prevent it from rerendering at all and how? Thanks in advance.

```
        const [catName, setcatName] = useState('')
        const [catWeight, setcatWeight] = useState('')
        const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
        let allGood = false;
        const handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            if(catWeight <= 100) {
                allGood = true
            }
            if(catWeight < 1) {
                allGood = false
            }
            if(allGood) {
                setCategories([{ catName, catWeight }, ...categories])
            } else alert("Something went wrong!")
            
        }
        ...
           return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label>
                Enter Category Name:
                <input
                    required
                    autoCapitalize="words"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    type="text"
                    name="cat-name"
                    value={catName}
                    onChange={
                        (e) => {setcatName(e.target.value)
                        e.preventDefault()}
                    }
                />
                <br/>
                Enter Category Weight:
                <input
                    required
                    autoComplete="off"
                    type="number"
                    name="cat-name"
                    value={catWeight}
                    onChange={
                        (e) => setcatWeight(e.target.value)
                    }  
                />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
          </form>
        
        {/* displaying new category */}
        <div id="display-categories">
            {categories.map(({ catName, catWeight }) => (
                <Category key={uuid()} name={catName} weight={catWeight}/>
            ))}
        </div>

        </div>
      );
```

Comment: wdym by *keeping children while re-rendering* ?

Comment: @KcH When the parent component gets re-rendered from `      setCategories([{catName, catWeight }, ...categories])` , the children are gone. I want to know how to keep the children.

Comment: but what do `categories` have ... can you add its data ?

Comment: @KcH `categories` has an array that contains the previous values of `catName` and `catWeight`. It starts as an empty array and you can add data from its form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer: don't use `key={uuid()}`

keys should stay the same between rerenders of components. with the way you do it each rerender a new key is generated (which makes itso that react views them always as completely new components (since the new components have different keys to the current one)). This causes every component to get reinitialised on each rerender of the parent.

If you however use a key, that stays constant between rerenders this problem will cease to exist.

So do something like `key={cat name}` or add a unique id property to your cats and use that. But the important thing is your key has to be consistent between rerenders of the component. Otherwise React can't keep track of which components are the same.

Edit: When a component is rerendered React basically checks the keys of it's children to see if there are any that stayed the same. But since you call uuid() on each rerender (which creates a new and unique key on each rerender) React will never be able to spot the same components in your case